# debugging numpy.float32('1.5').__mul__()

Tags: python, numpy, clang

In our application ([Sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org)) numpy is used alongside with types it does not know, i.e. we expect `numpy.float32('1.5').__mul__(x)` do not do anything, i.e. give it back to Python with `NotImplemented` whenever `x` is of such a type. It turns out that we have a type for which `numpy` emits a warning, if compiled with `clang` (no problems with `gcc`):

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply`

before giving up. (more details [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9007) and [here](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/22799)) How does one debug this?

`type(x)` is  `sage.rings.polynomial.polynomial_real_mpfr_dense.PolynomialRealDense`
and `len(dir(x))` is 301, so I'd rather add it as a [link](https://gist.github.com/dimpase/e032c48cabb24995cca3d1bc6f6a85e0).

Comment: at least it would be nice to understand how to simplify the test so that it does not need Sagemath, but only some data one can create in Python directly.

Comment: Can you show `type(x)` and `dir(x)`, so we can see what APIs NumPy might be trying to use to interact with your object?

Comment: please see the edited question.

Comment: A quick check seems to show that NumPy will actually call your object's `__rmul__` inside NumPy's `__mul__`, so you should investigate your object's `__rmul__`.

Comment: `x.__rmul__(numpy.float32('1.5'))` goes through without a warning, so this most probably means that it does something, resulting in the warning, before invoking `x.__rmul__` (or perhaps after, I don't know).

Comment: Are you sure that's not just because the warning already happened once with `numpy.float32('1.5').__mul__(x)`, and it's being suppressed by default the second time?

Comment: There is no suppression, the warning pops up  at every invocation of `numpy.float32('1.5').__mul__(x)`.